# Best practices of theming/skinning an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

What are some best practices of theming/skinning an iOS app?

Examples:

- Using custom images as screen backgrounds.
- Modifying the look of UITableView tables.
- Buttons with a custom look.

Links to good tutorials are a plus.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a protocol that defines methods to return theme-specific colors, images, etc. All classes that conform to this protocol have to implement these methods.

```
@protocol MyCustomThemes <NSObject>
-(UIFont*)writingAreaFont;
-(UIColor*)dataCellLabelColor;
-(UIImage*)dataCellBackgroundImage;
@end
```

Comment: This is how Apple themselves did it for Find My Friends, as seen in WWDC 2012 video of Session 216 Advanced Appearance Customization on iOS

Comment: You're right. I didn't mention it because I wasn't sure if we're allowed to talk about those.

Comment: Thanks! Does this method add value if you only have one theme (like "Find My Friends")?

Comment: Yes, collecting all your "style" definitions in one file saves time when you want to update the theme later.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest that:

1. Make theme class
2. Make function to return background image(s)
3. Make function to return data cell.
4. make any required function in the theme class.

the init function should have one parameter to plist file that contains the assets(images) that will be needed for your class to work properly. it should be a plist file that contains a dictionary for a predefined keys.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You might take a look at [NUI](https://github.com/tombenner/nui), which lets you modify the theme/skin of an app very easily, and save that theme for other apps, too.

For example, if you wanted to use a custom image for the background of all of your UIViews, you would just put the following in the NUI style sheet:

```
ViewBackgroundImage    String    MyImage.png
```

NUI supports styling for UITableViews and UIButtons, too (as mentioned in your other examples).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [Freestyle](http://pixate.com/freestyle). It's built on [Pixate](http://pixate.com), and styles your app with structured Sass. You can do as little as change the variable values to make a new theme, or extend and customize it via CSS or Sass.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but still - if you're looking for best practices, then [`UIAppearance`](http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/) is probably it.

However, if you're looking for a more powerful way to style your app (and create themes) - also have a look at [InterfaCSS](http://www.interfacss.org). InterfaCSS uses stylesheets inspired by CSS (and Less/Sass) that support a rich selector syntax and lets you use standard UIKit property names.

Comment: I love the way you've implemented InterfaCSS. Seems very lightweight and non-intrusive. Solves one problem (DRY). I'd much prefer to use this over the other monolithic styling solutions that are out there (I really don't need all the editors and cloud sharing stuff that Pixate offers). Do you have plans to work on an Android version of InterfaCSS anytime soon?

Answer (score 1):

I know this may be late but I've stumbled upon a theme framework called [Pixate](http://www.pixate.com/). Pixate allows you to theme all your components using css. It's native meaning no web views and what not AND its fairly easy to implement in an existing project. Check it out.

Comment: Update->Pixate was acquired by Google and has shut down.